# php explode uppercase lowercase

Tags: php, explode

```
$str='<html>...<header>...</header>...</html>';
//$str='<HTML>...<HEADER>...</HEADER>...</HTML>';
$header = explode("<header>", $str, 2);
echo $header[1];
```

I have many html code, I want explode `header` tag, but some `uppercase` and some are `lowercase`, cause the `$str` is very huge, I do not want use `str_replace()` change them all to  `uppercase` or `lowercase`, is there any easy way to explode `header` tag for 2 part from a `$str`? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way - preg_split() function!

Didn't test the regex, but i think this is what you're looking for:

```
$header = preg_split("/<header>/i", $str);
```

Comment: There is no need to escape `<` and `>` so `$header = preg_split('/<header>/i', $str);` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

To use explode and uppercase, you may opt for the following solution:

```
$pieces = explode(" ", strtoupper($pizza));
```

Hope this would work for you.

Thanks